# Automatically Store String Data Externally For Later Use in Java

Tags: java, string, input

I have a basic User Input and System Output program using strings, and at the start of the program it asks for the user's name, which it saves as a string variable inside the program.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Hello there! What's your name?");
String name = input.nextLine();
```

What I want is for the program to save all new names it receives in an external file (like a 
text file), and whenever a name is input it checks to see if it has encountered that name before. I want to use an if / else statement to have it display a different output depending on whether or not it has seen that name before. How do I go about accomplishing this?

~

My apologies if this is a basic problem (or if it has been answered before), but I am relatively new to java and I wasn't able to find a solution.  Thank you for your help! ^-^

Comment: Do you know how to (1) write to a file in Java and (2) read from a file in Java?

Comment: I've been creating Java projects and classes using Eclipse, writing to the classes, and then compiling and executing the program within Eclipse. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Indirectly, yes it does. You'll need to break this problem up into several steps. What you're really trying to do is the following, as far as the computer is concerned: Open a file with a specific name, call it C:\myFile.txt; if the file does not exist, create it. Write to the end of the file some user input, then save it and close it. That's the writing portion, which is half of your question and a lot for a beginner to start with. Look into the `File` class in `java.io.*`;  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html for the basics

Comment: Thank you very much! This is extremely helpful! ^_^ I was able to get Java to write a text file using the input name as the file name and content. Do you perchance know a simple statement I can use to have java check to see if the file is there, and return a boolean depending  on whether it is or not?

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to use this method: `File.createNewFile("C:\\myDirectory\\myFile.txt")`. This will create a new file only if a file does not exist and will return `true` if it creates a new file, otherwise `false`. From the javadocs, it says `Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.`

boolean isNewFile = File.createNewFile("C:\\myDirectory\\myFile.txt");
if (isNewFile == true) { //do stuff }

Comment: hmm.. whenever I try to run `File.createNewFile("C:\\myDirectory\\myFile.txt")` it tells me: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method createNewFile() in the type File is not applicable for the arguments (String)`
This seems like just what I need, if I can get it to work ^_^ I did import java.io.File, as well.

Comment: Create a File object first `File file = new File("C:\\myDirectory\\myFile.txt");` Then create the physical file `file.createNewFile()`. `createNewFile()` doesn't take arguments. Or you can do `System.out.println("File created? " + file.createNewFile());` To check whether or not the file was created.

Comment: @peeskillet is right, I made a mistake. The `createNewFile()` method doesn't take arguments, which you can see on the Javadocs page linked above. The suggestion in his response above is best.

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work just as I wanted! Thank you both so much for your help! ^-^

Answer (score 0):

I think this program may accomplished your requirement

```
public static void main(String as[]) throws Exception{
int i=0;
File f1=new File("D:\\Name.txt");
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f1,true);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner output=new Scanner(f1);
System.out.println("Hello there! What's your name?");
String name = input.nextLine();
if(!f1.exists()){
    f1.createNewFile();
}
else{
        while(output.hasNext()){
            String na=output.next();
            if(na.equals(name)){
                ++i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==0)
            fw.write(name+" ");
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter some different name");
        }

}
fw.close();
input.close();
output.close();

}
```